# Z3 Java-API: Is there a function to match the regular expression?

Tags: z3

I have a problem using Z3 Java-API to compare the String with the regular expression.

For some target regular expressions:

```
"^[a-zA-Z]"
```

When I try to match the Strings with the regular expressions, it is still recognized as a string. For example:

```
SeqExpr c1 = ctx.mkString("^[a-zA-Z]");
ReExpr c2 = ctx.mkToRe(ctx.mkString("abc"));

s.add(ctx.mkInRe(c1, c2));
s.check();

System.out.println("c1 = " + c1);
System.out.println("mkInRe = " + ctx.mkInRe(c1, c2));
System.out.println(s.check());
```

The result is:

```
c1 = "^[a-zA-Z]"
mkInRe = (str.in.re "^[a-zA-Z]" (str.to.re "abc"))
UNSATISFIABLE
```

The "^[a-zA-Z]" whole part is recognized as a string but not a regular expression.

And I found that [Defining constraints in Z3 using Boolean operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53808101), this question would be highly related, Can something similar about the regular expression be done in Z3 Java?

Thanks!

Comment: Just like in the Python answer you linked, there's no function to convert a string to a regular-expression object in Java either. You'll have to construct your regular-expression piecemeal using the simpler functions in the API. See: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/b0d5b242f1710c7e65b55c0885d4a46028bb93d4/src/api/java/Context.java#L2100-L2201

Comment: This would require a new compiler from Java (or Python) strings to Z3-regexp, which can definitely be done, but so far I think nobody has done it. Z3 gladly accepts contributions though!

Comment: @LeventErkok Thanks for your reply! But I still kind of confused, I tried to use these function but the function does not implement. Would you please be more specific?
For example, I want to check whether in the string "I love Z3" have "love" in it, what should I do? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ChristophWintersteiger Thanks for your reply! I will try my best to do it!